# Contract execution

Tags: parity

Are there any recommended guides that would demonstrate how to transfer ether from a deployed contract to accounts? Or any on the details of execution in Parity? I am having difficulty moving my ether from older contracts to the accounts that own them...

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  The title is among the most important when asking a question, so try to be more specific.  Do you mean "How to transfer ether from a contract wallet in Parity?"